# reading a bin file with php bin2hex function

Tags: php, hex, fopen, bin

I am trying to read a bin file that contains a lots of two 4-byte numbers in it, which I want to read and convert to hex numbers that is then going to be printed to the screen.... hopefully however I am having a little trouble getting my head around this one. this is what I have so far from reading examples and documentation..

```
<?php

$handle = @fopen("files/bigbin1.bin", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $hex = bin2hex($handle);
    }
    fclose($handle);

}

print_r($hex);
?>
```

I am 95% sure the error is in passing $handle over to tbin2hex.. but this being my first ever reading of a bin file I am slightly lost. the overall goal at some point will be to read the bin file into the database however I am just trying to figure out what this file looks like on screen.

Comment: You can't pass the handle directly to bin2hex.

Comment: yea, thats what I was thinking right after testing.. just did'nt quite know how to express that thought in words :) still getting my head around a few things its been a few years since I played with php and even then it was fairly basic stuff so catching on slowly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

$handle = @fopen("files/bigbin1.bin", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $hex = bin2hex(fread ($handle , 4 ));
        print $hex."\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);

}

?>
```

EDIT:  Also you should avoid using `@` it can make debugging extremely frustrating.

Comment: The problem states that the numbers are 4 bytes long, should it be `fread($handle, 4)`?

Comment: @Keoki Zee: Yes you are right, sorry I misread it as 2 4 bit long integers.

Comment: This worked perfectly, sorry I didn't mark it earlier was playing around with further concepts with this example :) thanks again :P